# Wifi management with pyjnius

Tags: python, kivy, pyjnius

With Python and Kivy I have created a simple app with showing landscapes, I would only let it work with the wifi and mobile network, but i'm a beginner looking for someone who helps me. Thanks and regards

Comment: Checkout examples in Plyer https://github.com/kivy/plyer

Comment: Plyer not support wifi android i need a complete code i m a beginner Thanks Priyank Mehta

Comment: what do you exactly mean by working with wifi and mobile data?

Comment: I mean, my app must work only with wifi or mobile network because ads are only shown with an internet connection, then I need to register to admob and understand how to put ads in my app and then publish it to play store. My app is  free and I want to earn with ads admob.An offline application does not load admob ads........Sorry my english Regards